# How to render a UIView whose subview's layer has a `compositingFilter`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, core-graphics

I want to render a UIView into a UIImage, but some subviews of that UIView have set blend mode using `layer.compositingFilter`, these views will render without blend mode, such as:

```swift
view.layer.compositingFilter = "multiplyBlendMode"
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-render):

> The OS X v10.5 implementation of this method does not support the entire Core Animation composition model. QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, and QTMovieLayer layers are not rendered. Additionally, layers that use 3D transforms are not rendered, nor are layers that specify backgroundFilters, filters, compositingFilter, or a mask values. Future versions of macOS may add support for rendering these layers and properties.

My render code:

```swift
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
format.scale = 1.0
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size, format: format).image { context in
    self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
}
```

How to render a view with blend mode like multiply blend mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drawHierarchy`

```swift
UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds).image { context in
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```